# Video stuck at first frame

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I just got my hands on AR.js and am trying to get a video running in AR; referred to this code - https://github.com/jeromeetienne/ar.js#augmented-reality-for-the-web-in-less-than-10-lines-of-html and tweaked it referring to other posts and blogs. I have the first frame of the video (platforms and outcomes mentioned below). However, it doesn't play.

Platforms - ***Outcome***

1. Mac OS 10.12, Chrome 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit) -
   ***video stuck at first frame*** Mac OS 10.12, Safari 10.0 (12602.1.50.0.10) - *Camera error - "WebRTC issue-!
   navigator.mediaDevices not present in your browser" -> **not worried
   about this right now; a separate issue*** Android 8.0.0 (OnePlus
   3T), Chrome 68.0.3440.91 - ***black plane, not sure if video loads
   or not***

My target platforms are iOS and Android both. Couldn't try on iOS as I have the only Android device.

Here is my tweaked code:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.6.1/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/1.5.0/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"> </script>
  <body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
    <a-scene embedded arjs='sourceType: webcam; detectionMode: mono; trackingMethod: best; debugUIEnabled: false;' vr-mode-ui="enabled: false">
      <a-assets>
          <video crossOrigin="anonymous" id="vid" autoplay loop="true" type="video/mp4" src="sv.mp4">
      </a-assets>
      <a-marker preset="hiro">
          <a-video src="#vid" width="1.78" height="1" rotation="270 0 0" play="true"></a-video>
      </a-marker>
    <a-entity camera></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

I also tried using the latest version of JS scripts,

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar.min.js"></script>
```

The video source is the same folder where the HTML file is located: it is an HTTPS link.

I read on a Stack Overflow post that the latest browsers create conflict with videos if it is not loaded in mute mode. So, tried the below as well, but none works.

```
autoplay loop muted="true"
autoplay muted="true"
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks

---

**Edit**

I just checked the log in Console (Chrome on Mac) and saw this error,

*Mixed Content: The page at 'https://MY_SERVER_URL/web-ar/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.loadingpage.info/jo/is?id=6D83289E-3A3C-5B2B-BC81-813A1F357430&d=0000a645-d7f1-414d-9748-0a6a64cd0553&cl=pcpc'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.*

This error appears even before I scan the Hiro marker. Post-scanning the marker, the plane loads with the first screen of the video

Answer (score 0):

getUserMedia requires a secure origin (i.e. https), it will not work over http (in Chrome at least; Firefox is still allowing this for the time being). Get a certificate, possibly via letsencrypt.

Comment: the server where my HTML code and media files are hosted is already HTTPS. I am not sure from where did this link come up (http://www.loadingpage.info/jo/is?id=6D83289E-3A3C-5B2B-BC81-813A1F357430&d=0000a645-d7f1-414d-9748-0a6a64cd0553&cl=pcpc), I am guessing it is from the JS that is being used..